# converter class test driven

Tags: java, tdd, converters

I have a class, which should convert data from one format into another (Database to LibraryType). It looks like:

```
public LibraryType convertToLibrary(Database db, Parameters params) {

    Preconditions.checkNotNull(db," missing database for conversion");
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(params, "missing parameters for conversion");

    LibraryType lib = basicFactory.createLibraryType();
    lib.setName(db.getName());
    ComponentType type = convertStructure(db.getStructure(),params);

    if (type != ComponentType.EMPTY) {
        lib.addComponent(type);
    }

    return lib;
}

ComponentType convertStructure(Structure s, Parameters params) {

   if (!params.isStructureAllowed(s)) return ComponentType.EMPTY;

   ComponentType comp = basicFactory.createComponentType();       
   comp.setName(s.getName());
   return comp;
}
```

I have two problems with this concept.

1. The method convertStructure should be private, because it is not neccessary to call it from the outside, but for testing purposes I defined it package-wide, which does not look so nice
2. The Parameters (params) are passed to the sub-method. Actually I would use a class field for that which could be insert during constructor, but because of using guice as DI-framework, I cannot pass this data into the constructor. Parameters will change during runtime. So I need to pass it as a method parameter. I could set it to the class field in the convertToLibrary method, but then I cannot test the method convertStructure.

Did I run into a design problem or are there any useful workarounds? Does it make sense to split it into different classes, which does not sound so good to me, because I still feel it is one responsibility (SRP) in the class (converting the data)?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Answer for question 1 (and perhaps question 2):

If you feel you need to write a test for `convertStructure()`, I think it is a sign that it should be in its own class. A test should not test things smaller that a single responsibility (IMO).

That said, I'm not sure you need to test `convertStructure()` in isolation. Isn't testing `convertLibrary()` enough? Or perhaps an even larger unit?

*Opinion: I have the preference of testing outside in, testing at a high level to start with and testing smaller parts when I need to. Start testing the behaviour, as seen from the user of your system, and test implementation details only when needed. Not everyone agrees with me though.*

Comment: it is not the full class. In convertStructure, there will come later even another call, for converting a subelement of structure and so on. So in the end, it can happen, that you will have 5 different if statements (in each method maybe one), so that it will increase the number of test methods

Comment: It can happen. But maybe it won't. The TDD way is to do what's best for the moment. Once you discover new things, change/adapt the test and/or production code to the new knowledge.